# Why does GCP Dataflow Pipeline throws Python UnicodeDecode Error?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, kubeflow

I have a Kubeflow pipeline that calls Dataflow to execute a Job but I keep having the same issue:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', 'download', '--dest', '/tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache', '-r', '/tmp/requirements.txt', '--exists-action', 'i', '--no-binary', ':all:']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

For what I have seen so far, pip doesn't support anymore the download option and thus the pipeline fails.
However, investigating further I have another message from the rsa==4.0.0 module where it has an UnicodeDecode Error that should be already fixed according to its [Github Issue](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/53116)
The error is the following:

```
Saved /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/rsa-4.0.tar.gz
          Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
          Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
            File "/tmp/pip-build-z1xp0h1i/rsa/setup.py", line 20, in <module>
              long_description = f.read()
            File "/usr/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
              return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
          UnicodeDecodeError: \'ascii\' codec can\'t decode byte 0xc3 in position 898: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Also, this is how I call the Dataflow pipeline.

```
pipeline_args.extend(
        [
            "--runner=DataflowRunner",
            "--project={PROJECT_ID}",
            "--staging_location={STAGE_BUCKET}",
            "--temp_location={TEMP_BUCKET}",
            f"--job_name={JOB_NAME}-{str(uuid.uuid4())[:6]}",
            f"--requirements_file={REQUIREMENTS_LOCAL}",
            "--region={}".format(REGION),
        ]
    )
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this execute dataflow by running a command line process? Can you please print the full command line used, rather than the argument list containing the format strings. I can help on the Dataflow side, but I am not too sure about the kubeflow side. In this case the stack trace doesn't show anything dataflow specific. This looks like you are passing some sort of string that can't be decoded. You may need to use codecs or unicode to resolve this type of error, which is quite common when using special characters in python.

Comment: Since this looks like its coming from setup.py, would you ming sharing your setup.py file? Also PTAL at this blog on character encodings https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2014/12/understanding-python-unicode-str-unicodeencodeerro/ When I had encountered python issues like this in the past, I did a mix of using unicode instead of strings, setting the encoding on those strings and on the python file itself, to get things working.

Comment: I think this comment may answer both of your comments, I have opened an issue on Kubeflow Pipelines project https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/3315
This happens when triggering the pipeline from inside a container, so dataflow needs to build its dependencies (inside its own execution machine) that are in the requirements file provided via command line option.
The dataflow pipeline is called via python code with an ApacheBeam pipeline on it.